# Building dynamic web applications

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, web-applications

I have created a student tracking system for my local community college using PHP, MySql, and HTML (the usual suspects). I am at version 2 of the project. It has yet to be finished. As now my next step in this project is to make it "come alive". Currently I have been reading up on AJAX and Jquery. To my understanding Jquery is a library of Javascript that you can download (the plain text format) and include into your scripts. What I am confused with is where should I start this next step? I am extremely new to Jquery/Javascript and no where near understanding AJAX. From what I have read, Jquery has its own implementation of AJAX built in.

Are there any good reading resources our there? I currently downloaded Jquery in Action, head first jquery, and ajax the definitive guide from Oreilly. Is there anything else I should know about Jquery / AJAX? I am a novice that is looking to further broaden his horizon of knowledge. A guide in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The jQuery Bible: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: "where should I start this next step?" — I'd start by redefining the step. "Come alive" is a vague goal. Have something concrete to aim for.

Comment: Well I want to have my tables be more interactive. I don't want my fellow co-workers have to hit the F5 to see which new students are waiting for them. I want that sort of information to be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

With the books you have and the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) api suggested by *Rory McCrossan* you should do just fine. Any other problem that you might encounter while implementing features, that is not described in these books (Head First's books are a great starting point), can be solved just by googling.

Another useful thing about jQuery is it's plugins. They are out-of-the-box libraries that you can use as they are, simply by calling their functions. Here are a couple of web locations where you can find them:

- [Official jQuery plugin archive](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/)
- [50 jQuery plugins](http://speckyboy.com/2012/12/10/jquery-plugins-2012/)
- [40 useful jQuery plugins](http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/40-awesome-jquery-plugins-you-need-to-check-out/)
- ["best" jQuery plugins of 2012](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/best-jquery-plugins-of-2012)
- [HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/) - Very nice plugin for creating interactive tables
- [TableSorter](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/393/Tablesorter-jQuery) - Another great plugin for sorting html table data

Answer (score 1):

jquery has an official guide for the basic version @: [JQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com)

you will find a documentation to almost each and every plugin you download on the site you got it from ;)
furthermore you can of course ask questions on SO and google almost any problem you might have.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this perfect article:
[**5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

*functions that explained in the above article*:

- **load()**: Load a piece of html into a container DOM.
- **$.getJSON()**: Load a JSON with GET method.
- **$.getScript()**: Load a JavaScript.
- **$.get()**: Use this if you want to make a GET call and play extensively with the response.
- **$.post()**: Use this if you want to make a POST call and don’t want to load the response to some container DOM.
- **$.ajax()**: Use this if you need to do something when XHR fails, or you need to specify ajax options (e.g. cache: true) on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery & AJAX together look like that:

```
$('div#id').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: "id=1",
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data == "Success") {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```